# WP Вывод комментариев через пагинацию, как контролировать порядок вывода?

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

В WordPress в настройках админки в вкладке `Settings -> Discussion` Есть `<select>` вывода комментариев

[image: comments wordpress]

Break comments into pages with 5  top level comments per page and the first page displayed by default ... Как в запросах вывода списка управлять этими first/last ? (*Так что б он не назначался с админки, а брались из аргументов запроса)
Предположим, что у меня есть вот такой вывод комментариев.

```
<?php if (post_password_required()) {
    return;
}
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$per_page = 4;
$comments_count = get_comments_number($post_id);

if (isset($_GET['cpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['cpage'])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['cpage'];
}
$page = max(1, $page);

?>
<div id="comments" class="company-rewiew-list">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'type' => 'comment',
        'reverse_top_level' => false, // Отключаем сортировку родительских комментариев от старых к новым
        'reverse_children' => false, // Отключает сортировку ответов на родительские комментарии от новых к старым
        'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'cpage' => $page,
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php

/// Pagination
if (($per_page > 1) && ($comments_count > $per_page)) {
    include locate_template('template-parts/custom-comments-pagination.php');
}
?>
```

И мне необходимо, что б нажимая на кнопку на фронтовой части, создавался запрос, который вернул бы мне этот массив из комментариев, но в другом порядке - От позних к ранним. Как это реализовать ?